# How to fix 301 Moved permanently for Ajax request

Tags: ajax, symfony, http-status-code-301

My ajax request is runnnig in a perfect way on my host but whenever the application is installed on the server all the request have the status "301 Moved permanently".

I already passed 3 days debuging this but no way. I don't know why i'm getting this. I'm using Symfony2.

This is the request on the server side:

```
$('#edit').click(function () {
    var $validEmail = $('#mail').validator({
        type: 'error',
        rules: [{
            control: 'email',
            message: 'Format invalide'
        }]
    });
    var $validpost_code = $('#post_code').validator({
        type: 'error',
        rules: [{
            control: 'required',
            message: 'Code postal obligatoire'
        }]
    });
    var $validRs = $('#rs').validator({
        type: 'error',
        rules: [{
            control: 'required',
            message: 'Raison sociale obligatoire'
        }]
    });
    var $validAddr = $('#addr').validator({
        type: 'error',
        rules: [{
            control: 'required',
            message: 'Adresse obligatoire'
        }]
    });
    var $validPhone_number = $('#phone_number').validator({
        type: 'error',
        rules: [{
            control: 'required',
            message: 'Tel obligatoire'
        }]
    }) && $('#phone_number').validator({
        type: 'error',
        rules: [{
            control: 'phone',
            message: 'Format requise mask: +33 # ## ## ## ##'
        }]
    });

    var $validCountry = $('#country').validator({
        type: 'error',
        rules: [{
            control: 'required',
            message: 'Ville obligatoire'
        }]
    });
    var $validTown = $('#town').validator({
        type: 'error',
        rules: [{
            control: 'required',
            message: 'Pays obligatoire'
        }]
    });
    var $valid3897 = $('#3897').validator({
        type: 'error',
        rules: [{
            control: 'required',
            message: 'Forme juridique obligatoire obligatoire'
        }]
    });
    if ($validEmail && $validpost_code && $validRs && $validAddr && $validPhone_number && $validTown && $valid3897 && IsPosInteger($('#post_code').find('input').val())) {
        var data = {
            name: $('#name').find('input').val(),
            id: "{{client.id}}",
            post_code: $('#post_code').find('input').val(),
            rs: $('#rs').find('input').val(),
            address: $('#addr').find('input').val(),
            email: $('#mail').find('input').val(),
            effectif: $('#efectif').find('input').val(),
            turnover: $('#turnover').find('input').val(),
            siteWeb: $('#site').find('input').val(),
            phone_number: $('#phone_number').find('input').val(),
            country: $('#country').find('input').val(),
            town: $('#town').find('input').val(),
            fax: $('#number').find('input').val(),
            kbis: $('#bis').find('input').val(),
            vat: $('#vat').find('input').val(),
            legal_form: $('#3897').find('select').val(),
            active: $('#active').attr('checked'),
            groupe: $('#groupe').find('input').val(),
            business_sector: $('#sa').find('input').val()
        };
        $("#site_content").block();
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{url('Update_client')}}",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                data: ODEANCE.toJson(data)
            },
            success: function (updateResponse) {
                if (updateResponse) {
                    $("#site_content").unblock(),
                    jAlert('Modification effectuée  avec sucées ', 'Modification') //,
                    //document.location=document.location
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        jAlert('Veuillez vérifier les formats de vos champs', 'Modification');
    }
});
```

and here the method in the controller:

```
public function updateClientAction() {
    try {
        //Getting sended data 
        $data = $this->getRequest()->get('data');
        $data = \json_decode(\stripslashes($data));
        $spi = $this->get('spi');
        $clientManager = $spi->getClientManager();
        $updateResponse =($clientManager->update($data) == true ) ?  1 : 0;
        return new Response($updateResponse);
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        $updateResponse = 0;
        return new Response($updateResponse);
    }
}
```

It seems that the response of the request cannot return to the origin location (of the request).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days, the problem is fixed now. it was a conflict betwwen http and https request so all i did is forcing my application to the https side with this line is the security.yml

```
access_control:        
      - { path: ^/,role: ROLE_USER, requires_channel: https }
```

Thanks everyone ^^

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps anyone else - I just had the same problem and resolved it by using path() instead of url(). Using url() the calls were directed to http and then redirected to https, which was likely causing the 301. Using path() the calls were directed straight to https.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to browse directly to `{{url('Update_client')}}`
2. Check your html source if the output of `{{url('Update_client')}}` is correct

Comment: No it doesn't work. The problem that is always working on my host. Could it be a problem of cache ? the header of the request display Cache-Control  private

Comment: you say all the requests return 301, is that every page of you're application? seems more like a server configuration.

Comment: yes all the ajax request are moved :/ the problem that it's not me who installed it on the server but i have to debug it the manager said that the problem should be rectified on my side but i have no idea what can it be :/ that's why i said can it be a problem of cache

Comment: To my knowledge the Cache-control directive cannot be the problem, private means that it can only be cached per one user (browser-cache).  And has normally nothing to do with a 301 redirect. You still could try to clear your browser-cache and see if that helps. Are these application-urls you are creating new ones or did they exist before?

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) yes i cleared the browser cache but the problem is always here. For the URLs they exist already but what i have understand from google:p is that maybe the return of new Response() doesn't know where to go which means that the request doesn't keep the Refered page but i have no idea why

Comment: I'm affraid i cannot help you with that (my knowledge in that area is very limited.). But i know that a 301 is always issued on server-level (either by the web-server or your application) and since your application doesn't do it, it must be the server. Maybe you should talk to the server-administrator again..

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, okay i ll try to fix it asap nd i ll let u know the solution ;) i hope that :D

Answer (score 0):

Remove the trailing slash from pattern in routing.yml